# Usage of pseudo classes inside the css itself?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

```css
.obj1a,
.obj2b,
.obj3c
{
    border: 1px solid #c6ffc7;
}

.obj1a:hover:not(:focus),
.obj2b:hover:not(:focus),
.obj3c:hover:not(:focus)
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: 2px solid white;
}

.obj1a:focus,
.obj2b:focus,
.obj3c:focus
{
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

The code above is what I'm currently using, and it works just fine. However, I was wondering if there's any easier way to do it. Like using pseudo classes inside the css itself, like shown below. Is it possible to do something like that?

```css
.obj1a,
.obj2b,
.obj3c
{
    border: 1px solid #c6ffc7;
}

.obj1a,
.obj2b,
.obj3c
{
    border:hover:not(:focus): 1px solid white;
    outline:hover:not(:focus): 2px solid white;
    border-width:focus: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no such use. But you can build a different structure with SCSS:

```css
.obj1a, .obj2b, .obj3c {
  border: 1px solid #c6ffc7;
  
  &:focus {
    border-width: 3px;
  }
  
  &:hover:not(:focus) {
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: 2px solid white;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="obj1a">obj1a</button>
<button class="obj2b">obj1a</button>
<button class="obj3c">obj1a</button>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work for me. I remade the file to a `.scss`, and added the `&:focus {outline: 2px solid white;}`, but nothing happend.

Comment: Changing the file extension to scss is unfortunately not enough. You also need to create a structure that converts SCSS to CSS. This is possible with the concept of "pre-processor". 

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_preprocessor

Please see also the other benefits of SCSS: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is not allowed but you could simplify a bit the code using an attribute selector. Also, you could control the values using some custom properties (variables)

```css
[class^="obj"] {
  border: var(--bw, 1px) solid var(--bc, #c6ffc7);
  outline: var(--ow, 0) solid #fff;
}

[class^="obj"]:hover:not(:focus) {
  --ow: 2px;
  --bc: #fff;
}

[class^="obj"]:focus {
  --bw: 3px;
}



body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-block-size: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #546fb2, #90b436);
  font: 1rem/2 system-ui;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="obj1a">obj 1a</a>
<a href="#" class="obj2b">obj 2b</a>
<a href="#" class="obj3c">obj 3c</a>
```